# Grafana - Is it possible to use variables in Loki-based dashboard query?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-loki, logql

I am working on a Loki-based Dashboard on Grafana. I have one panel for searching text in the Loki trace logs, the current query is like:

```
{job="abc-service"}
|~ "searchTrace"
|json
|line_format "{if .trace_message}} Message: \t{{.trace_message}} {{end}}"
```

Where `searchTrace` is a variable of type "Text box" for the user to input search text.

I want to include another variable `skipTestLog` to skip logs created by some test cron tasks. `skipTestLog` is a custom variable of two options: `Yes,No`.

Suppose the logs created by test cron tasks contain the text `CronTest` in the field `trace_message` after the `json` parser, are there any ways to filter them out based on the selected value of `skipTestLog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a key/value custom variable like in the following example:

[image]

Use the variable like in the following example:

[image]

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks!