# Template variable in another variable - Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Grafana version - v7.5.3

I have two “custom” variables -

`env` - has following values: test,prod

`instanceidtest` - someid

`instanceidprod` - anotherid

JSON example:

```
“targets”: [

    {

      "alias": "cpu",

      "dimensions": {

        "InstanceId": "$instanceid${env}"

      },
```

I want to template variable in another variable something like this - $instanceid${env} to become $instancetest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create just one custom variable called "env" like the following:

```
Values: test: someid,prod: anotherid
```

Note: the spaces are important

To get the id accordingly with the selected env use: ${env:value}

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621431/4653675) for more details.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. But I've faced another issue - how to get the name the variable if we will use `test: someid,prod: anotherid` type of the var definition? Because some panels point to the `test` or `prod` word in a query, e.g. - `jvm_memory_total_used_mb{exported_job="api-$env"}`

Comment: Great. Could you then accept the answer? To get the key of the variable use: ${env:text}